# Our cat has dry itchy "eyelids" and keeps scratching them, how to stop this?

Tags: cats, injury, eye-disease

Our cat has had an issue with both eyes for the last two weeks. It started with some small eye discharge (similar to "sleep" in our eyes) and infrequently watery however he seems to have taken to vigorously scratching under his eyes which I believe is the damage you can see in the images below.

[image]
[image]

**Am I wrong that the bald spots are simply from him scratching his eyes?**

**Should I wait another while and hope it clears up on its own or is this something I should visit the vet about?**

Answer (score 1):

See the vet. Maybe get a cone collar so he can't reach his eyes to scratch until the condition clears up.  Does the cat have fleas, mites, ticks?

Comment: We self apply flea treatment each month at home and he only itches his eyes, nowhere else. That was my first thought as he's started going outside hunting again with the better weather but I haven't seen anything on his fur. Good shout about the cone though, that makes sense.

Comment: going to the vet tomorrow morning, I'll report back!